# User Session Times out if multiple pages are open and one is left inactive using timer in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, logout, session-timeout

I have a user activity on my page. When user is inactive (**didnt move mouse**) for 30 minutes it prompts user warning that session will expire soon. If user does not click on **OK** button and stay inactive will be automatically logged out (**session destroy**).

Now this is being checked in every 25 minutes and everything works fine until user opens multiple tabs of same page. If multiple tabs are opened and user is working on one tab but left the other tab open for 25 minutes it times out.

How do i prevent it from timing out session when multiple tabs are open and user is active in at least one of the tabs meaning user is moving the mouse in at least one of the tabs of the page.

The js code that detects mouse move is below:

```
timer = 0;
function cIncrement() {
   if (timer == 25) {
     //25 minutes passed warn user that in 5 minutes it will expire
     //here is the code that prompts user with dialog
      if (OK clicked on dialog) {
        timer = 0;
      } else {
        //execute logout script.
      }
   }
   if (timer == 30) {
      //30 minutes passed log user out
      //script to log user out
   }
}

$(function() {
   var interval = setInterval("cIncrement()", 60000); //increment every minute

   //reset timer on mouse move
   $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      timer = 0;
   });
});
```

**NOTE**: the above code works fine when 1 tab is open.

how would i change this so that if 2 or more tabs are open and user is active in any of them should reset **timer** to **0**

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a server-side session object. Presumably you also have some kind of expiration time on your server-side session object, so you can reap sessions where users just close their browsers, or just close their laptop lids and go on vacation for a couple of weeks, etc. etc. Presumably activity whichever tab/window has focus resets your server-side activity timeout.

So, in `cIncrement`, initiate an Ajax request that asks the server how long ago the last activity was, and use the response to reset `timer`.

If you want to be really aggressive about keeping sessions open even if only mouse movement has been captured, send down your page's current value of timer and use it to move the session refresh time along if it was the most recent activity in that session.

Comment: but on each mousemove to send ajax request will slow it down since there will be a lot of ajax requests if mouse is moving constantly to update/reset timer

Comment: That would indeed slow it down. But what I meant was to send down the counter once a minute in cIncrement calls.